# add class via jquery but only when not exists

Tags: jquery, list

I would like to add a class (`class="bbox"`) to a ul-list but only if no class exists.
This is what I have so far. How do I check with jQuery if a class exists in the ul-tag?

```
$("ul").addClass("bbox");
```

Comment: There is no need to check if the class has already been added; `.addClass` will perform a `.hasClass` check internally. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13358887

Answer (score 25, accepted):

karim79  you almost got it !

let me correct you

```
$("ul:not([class*='bbox'])").addClass("bbox");
```

You match the tag with absolute no classes, and if ul had other classes the matching wouldn't be made. You got to search for the exactly class you wish to add. Like .hasClass aproach.

hope it helps

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you forgot brackets around the attribute selector. Also, `$("ul:not([class~='bbox'])").addClass("bbox");` would be better (tilde).

Answer (score 81):

Just use `$('.selector').addClass("myClass");`.

The jQuery add/remove class functions both check for duplicates internally, meaning that calling `addClass` twice only will add the class once.

Comment: from jQuery documents : https://api.jquery.com/addclass/ It's important to note that this method does not replace a class. It simply adds the class, appending it to any which may already be assigned to the elements.

Comment: @vanduc1102 If you mean that jQuery will duplicate class, you misunderstood the docs. The statement means that it does not replace all `class` attribute value. jQuery really checks for duplicity, and it was already covered by many QA here in SO.

Answer (score 60):

If you want to check if a specific class exists then:

```
 if(!$("ul").hasClass("class-name")){
    $("ul").addClass("bbox");
 }
```

If you want to check if any class exists:

```
if ($('ul').attr('class') == '') {
    $("ul").addClass("bbox");
}
```

Comment: I tried to select the first ul within #content but it selects all. what is wrong? if($('#content ul:nth-child(1)').hasClass("bbox") == false){
    $("ul").addClass("bbox");
 }

Comment: `hasClass()` already returns true or false so the check if equal to false is redundant. `if(!$('ul').hasClass('classname'))` would suffice

Comment: Regarding the specific classes thing, as of now jQuery already checks for the class before adding it with addClass

Answer (score 15):

I was wondering this would work fine -->

`$("ul").removeClass("bbox").addClass("bbox")`;

First it will remove if there is any and then add new one . Worked best for me as i am too lazy to type all that `if` thingy.

Answer (score 5):

If I'm toggling between 2 classes I use this method

```
if (foo)
    $('button.btn-foo').removeClass('foo bar').addClass('foo');
if (bar)
    $('button.btn-foo').removeClass('foo bar').addClass('bar');
```

So I don't have to check the current setting of the button

Answer (score 4):

you can use this code for adding class only when if not exist

```
$('.your-dom:not(.class-name)').addClass('class-name');
```

Answer (score 2):

Concisely:

```
// fine, because nothing happens if 
// there are no matching elements
$("ul[class='']").addClass("bbox");
```

Comment: Won't work if it has class abox and you're trying to add bbox. Matt's solution is solves this problem.

Answer (score 0):

To add a class (class="bbox") to a ul-list only if no class exists:

```
if (!$('ul').attr('class') == '') {
    $("ul").addClass("bbox");
}
```