# Should I use "hasClass" before "addClass"?

Tags: jquery, performance, addclass

I have come across the following script which checks whether an element has class `a`, and if not, adds it:

```
if (!$("div").hasClass("a")){
   $("div").addClass("a");
}
```

As jQuery won't add the class if it already exists, this could be changed to:

```
$("div").addClass("a");
```

However, is there any performance improvements by using `hasClass` first, or is this using the same method which `addClass` does anyway, and therefore duplicating the logic?

Answer (score 184, accepted):

The `.hasClass()` check is not useful because jQuery [will also always check](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/attributes/classes.js#L43-L45) from within `.addClass()`. It's just extra work.

Comment: Thank you for a link, it is wrong line heightlighted but the function does check `cur.indexOf( " " + clazz + " " ) < 0` meaning that the answer is correct.

Answer (score 13):

You can see at the source code : https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/attributes/classes.js#L38-L45 that they do check if the class exists when using `addClass`.

So there is no reason to use the `.hasClass()` in this case.. (*an exception would be if you wanted to perform more actions if the element did not have the class..*)

Comment: Hello from Thessaloniki and +1 -- I didn't know about the `#LX-Y` trick :)

Comment: Hey Jon :) It is mouse selectable as well..  (*click on line number and shift+click on another to select all lines..*)

Answer (score 6):

For what it's worth, there is a performance improvement with `.hasClass()` in my limited testing: http://jsperf.com/jquery-hasclass-vs-addclass-and-removeclass

However, even when standalone `.removeClass()` reports several times slower in Chrome, it comes in at approximately 70,000 operations a second.

Comment: Thanks, nice tool, however it is `addClass` in the question and `removeClass` in your testing.