# Do not add class if specific class exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

My navigation highlights the section of the page the visitor is on and changes as they scroll by adding .active-nav to ANY href that points to that section of the page. I have an image sprite that points to #foo but I don't want .active-nav added to that anchor tag. I am having no luck implementing the :not selector. I fear I have spent too much time on this and cannot see the obvious answer.

I would like to have the following code ignore an href tag if a specific class (.bar) already exists. Please advise.

```
if ( windowpos > $('#foo').offset().top) {
$('nav li a').removeClass('active-nav');
$('a[href$="#foo"]').addClass('active-nav');
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not suppose to be `'a[href!="#foo"]'`?

Comment: `$('nav li a').not("[href=#foo]")` doesn't work?

Comment: sorry, my op did not make clear that my code example does not contain my attempt to solve the problem. all of my attempts have failed.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8266662/add-class-via-jquery-but-only-when-not-exists

Comment: Do you need to check if an element has `.bar` class in the entire page before this code runs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) function:

```
$('a[href$="#foo"]').not('.bar').addClass('active-nav');
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
if($('a[href$="#foo"]').hasClass("bar")){
   //do stuff
} else {
   $('a[href$="#foo"]').addClass('active-nav');
}
```

Comment: this is very helpful too.