# jquery adding a class to styles only once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have code which allows adding a class to 'style' section.

```
function appendCssClassToStyle(clas, prprty, val)
{
  $('#myStyle').append('.' + clas + '{' + prprty + ':' + val + ';}');
}
```

This code adds the class many times. The problem is that I would like to be able to add a class only if it does not exist in the styles section yet. How can I do this? Thanks for help !

Comment: What does that renders to?

Comment: can you please add more description ? add you html  too. Thanks

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Whatever it is I can guarantee you there is a better and easier way

Comment: May I ask what your reason is to want new style declarations added directly to a `<style>` block? If you just want the element to change style please check my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should read up on the use of jQuery and how inline styles are added to html elements...

inline style:

```
<div class="someEl" style="background-color:#ff0000;">Some awesome text</div>
```

This element has a class `.someEl` which you can style in a CSS stylesheet:

```
.someEl {
    background-color:#fff; /* setting bg color to white */
    color:#000; /* setting font color to black */
}
```

Above would result in a div with a red (#ff0000) background since inline styles will overwrite styles from stylsheets.

With jQuery you can add and remove inline styles from the element.
Adding inline styles:

```
$('.someEl').css({
   'color': '#fff',
   'backgroundColor': '#ff0000'
});
```

Removing inline styles:

```
$('.someEl').css('backgroundColor', '');
```

Comment: That's not what the OP asked. He wants to add a CSS class definition into a <style> element.

Comment: @MarioCianciolo which itself is a bad idea. This is a better way, although I agree that the answer should have explained that. It is flawed though as `prprty` is a dynamic key, so this syntax won't work.

Comment: I agree that's a bad idea, but your answer is still invalid.

Comment: A yes, I thought he was trying to do `style=".className{prprty:val}"`

Comment: @MarioCianciolo nevertheless, I think the OP is trying to do what the `$.css()` function exists for..

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
$('.element:not(.class-name)').addClass('class-name');
```

as mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/33265116/2469264

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
function appendCssClassToStyle(clas, prprty, val)
{
  //var prprty = 'text-align';
  //var val = 'center';
  $('.' + clas).css(prprty,val);
}
```