# Use jQuery to wrap table in div and class, but only if table is not already wrapped

Tags: html, jquery, css

I'm attempting to wrap all of my table elements in the class `.table-container` but only if the class isn't already applied. This is the function that is working properly to add the styling:

```
attach: function (context, settings) {
    ("table").wrap("<div class='table-container'></div>")
}
```

What other jQuery needs to be applied to tell the function *not* to wrap the table element if the class is already being applied? (A third party manually wrapped some of the tables so I don't want to apply unnecessary CSS).

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do something like this

```
if(!$("table").hasClass("table-container")){
    $("table").wrap("<div class='table-container'></div>");
 }
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8266662/add-class-via-jquery-but-only-when-not-exists)